# Не работает условие (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity3d, if

```
if (joystick.Horizontal && joystick.Vertical != 0) {
  //code
  }
```

Почему не работает условие?

Консоль: Operator `&&' cannot be applied to operands of type`float' and `bool'

Answer (score 2):

У первой части условия вы пропустили оператор сравнения

```
if (joystick.Horizontal != 0 && joystick.Vertical != 0) 
{
//code
}
```